# Why got I this error on my UISwipeGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I got this error on my UISwipeGestureRecognizer in my custom class cell manager

[image]

It's working in my main UITableViewController class... I create a new instance in my ViewDidLoad with :

```
   let updateClass = updateCell()
   updateClass.swiper()
```

I'm not pretty sure but on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27086961/6155942), I should may be use lazy var to fix the issue but it doesn't change anything. What should I do ? Why I got this error please ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Your rightView is nil. Check IBOutlet connection

Comment: Indeed but why ? It's not nul on my main class...

Comment: Check connection with XIB/ Storyboard.

Comment: Everything seems work with the connection. Any idea ?

Comment: Make a break point at that line of code and check rightView in console

Comment: Check Johannes Starke's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48007821/7250862). Why are you creating new instance for UITableViewCell in viewDidLoad? When you create instance programmatically it doesn't initialise the storyboard properties. So rightview, middleview, leftview will be nil

Answer (score 2):

When you create a instance of updateClass like you the system won't load the view from the Storyboard (or Xib). This is the reason for nil error.

To load a table view cell from the storyboard you can use

```
let identifier = ... // the reusable identifier defined for this cell in storyboard

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! updateClass
```

Also you can't call this code in the viewDidLoad. You need to implement the UITableViewDataSource interface

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // load and return your cell 
}
```

Maybe this is a great tutorial for you
https://www.raywenderlich.com/77974/making-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1

Answer (score 0):

If your outlets are alright and `rightView` is not being over written anywhere then make sure you are calling `swiper()` on the main thread.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // your code here
 }
```

Try calling it like this. If threads are not synced then these kind of crazy behaviours happen.

Answer (score -2):

May be your rightView was nil. check your outlet connection

Comment: Everything seems good in my outlet connection... something to add may be ?

Comment: No need to add for this. This line will work. clean & build then run

Comment: Nothing change... I mean, what should I put in storyboard ? No error in it with right click... not alert, nothing.

Comment: remove your outlet and add it again. then run